# install windows after ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, windows-7

Sometimes ago I installed ubuntu on a drive which is not windows drive, but today Iformatted my windows drive to re-install windows, unfortunately I can not access to ubuntu? please help me!

Comment: Did you allow windows to automatically choose partitions, or did you specify which partitions to format? The former is not salvageable, the latter is a duplicate ^.

Comment: My window OS was in drive C and I formatted it, the ubuntu was on the drive "E" , but I can not access to ubuntu now?